# How do I backup DVDs and Blu-rays to my Mac?

Tags: macos, backup, dvd, blu-ray

I have begun to backup my DVDs and Blu-rays to my Mac using a combination of MakeMKV and Handbrake. I've noticed that this doesn't actually make a backup of the discs, but just creates an mkv file for each chapter.

Is there a better way to backup my DVDs and Blu-rays? Maybe as an iso file?

To me this seems a better option in case I want to re-rip the video from the disc at a later date.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/85987/mac-os-x-best-way-to-make-an-iso-from-a-cd-or-dvd

Answer (score 1):

Use `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility` to make a `.cdr` (iso) disk image from the DVDs.

Select the disk in the sidebar, then create a *New Image* from it.

Comment: If I have an external Blu-ray reader, would I be able to do the same with Blu-ray discs?